# How to let Internet Explorer continue running while the thread waits

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com

I am writing an application to open up Internet Explorer and use COM to control it. Below is a simplified "Browser" class I have written.

```
class Browser {
public:

    Browser() {
        if (FAILED(OleInitialize(NULL))) {
            throw 1;
        }
    }

    ~Browser() {
        OleUninitialize();
    }

    void open(const wchar_t* url) {

        HRESULT hr;
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorer, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
            IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&_pWebBrowser);

        if (FAILED(hr) || _pWebBrowser == NULL) { throw 1; }

        VARIANT vEmpty;
        VariantInit(&vEmpty);

        BSTR bstrUrl = SysAllocString(url);
        hr = _pWebBrowser->Navigate(bstrUrl, &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty);
        if (FAILED(hr)) { throw 1; }

        _pWebBrowser->put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE);
        SysFreeString(bstrUrl);

        //TODO: hook event listener
    }

private:
    CComQIPtr<IWebBrowser2> _pWebBrowser;
    CComQIPtr<IConnectionPoint> _pConnectionPoint;
    DWORD _adviseCookie;
};
```

The idea is to hook an event listener through [IConnectionPointContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692476(v=vs.85).aspx) and handle events as they happen. However, after the open funtion is finished the application closes and I am no longer able to continue controlling IE.

I have tried using the [wait functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) like so:

```
int main(){
    HANDLE hEvent = ::CreateEvent( /*...*/ );
    Browser* b = new Browser();

    b->open(_T("http://stackoverflow.com"));

    ::WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
}
```

But when I do that the browser won't continue navigation and will not fire events.

I have also tried a while loop with and without a sleep interval like so:

```
int main(){

    Browser* b = new Browser();

    b->open(_T("http://stackoverflow.com"));

    while(true){

        Sleep(1000); //Both with and without this sleep
    }
}
```

Internet explorer still doesn't continue execution.

**Question:**

What is the correct way to sleep the thread to allow IE to continue doing it's thing but prevent the app from closing.

Comment: Your tread joins single-threaded apartment, by way of calling `OleInitialize`. Therefore, it takes on the responsibility to run a message pump - to retrieve and dispatch window messages in a timely manner. See `GetMessage`, `DispatchMessage`.

Comment: For a quick test you can replace your `Sleep` with `MessageBox` call. Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12236639/868014) should give you some ideas.

Comment: @RomanR. Thanks so much for pointing me towards that question, it seems to pretty much be the same thing I was asking so I am going to mark this question as a duplicate.